# How many levels within a factor is too many for an ANOVA?

Tags: anova, mixed-model

I am running a mixed model with three factors.

It is labeled as a strip-split design. The vertical level is A, the horizontal level is B, the splits come from factor C (plant varieties). This is replicated in four blocks.

Factor A has 3 levels, Factor B has 5 levels, Factor C has 20 levels.

Will my model run better if I can knock Factor C down to five levels? What are my risks with so many factors and levels?

Comment: Why did you consider 20 levels for factor C in your study to begin with? Also, in your model, which of the 3 factors - if any - are considered random grouping factors?

Comment: Is this a re-asking of your [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/436729/grouping-by-subplot-in-mixed-effects-model) ? If so, you said this is a strip-split design. However, the data do not seem to conform to such a design. Please explain the design in detail.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement, the designers just had a lot of varieties to test. I consider block to be random.

Comment: @RobertLong, it is the same experiment. Do these details help?